# Neutral ground bonding in main service panel

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, grounding-and-bonding, meter

I purchased  a property with a 200 amp outdoor main service panel below the power company's meter. I want to use this to run power supply to my mobile home about 30 feet away. I also want to supply a workshop off this panel ran separately from tbe mobile home approx. 30 ft away.

It's my understanding that the main service panel closest to meter should be neutral grounded and only at the main panel. The other panels will be considered subpanels and all neutrals and grounds would remain separate. The first pic I have enclosed is a picture of the main 200 amp GE outdoor service panel connected to power company meter (via 3 wires).

[image: Main service panel]

The wires exiting the bottom of the panel will be removed as they were cut loose from whatever they previously had connected.

I have a 200 amp outdoor Homeline Square D panel from my previous property  I believe is a HOM816M200PFTRB. It was connected to a previous residence and removed. I need to determine if it is also neutral ground bonded and if so how can I undo that bond so I can use as a subpanel and also looks to me as both are neutral bars on either side with no ground bar attached. But can't tell if it is bonded. I want to use it as sub panel. Here is pic when it was wired:

[image: proposed Sub panel]

Comment: Neither panel seems to have a ground wire/connection/bus.  The neutral buses might be bonded to the panel's metal box, but that is only good if the panel is bonded to ground, by way of a metal conduit to ground or wire.  I will assume you know the bare neutral on the second box is bad, losing half of the stands, before connection lug.

Comment: Can you get us photos of the labeling on the inside left and right of the Homeline panel please?